# macOS Preview has graphical glitch when copying using rectangular selection

Tags: macos, pdf, preview, copy-paste

Whenever I open a .pdf (haven't tried with other formats) with many pages (at least > 5), Preview does this really annoying thing:

I use the Rectangular Selection tool to select an area of the .pdf I want to copy.
[image: rectangular selection area]

When I copy, the page does this:
[image: upon command+c, this happens (only for .pdfs that are many pages/large size)]

When I click the area off, then I can see the page again.
[image: as soon as I click again, it goes back to normal...]

Because I tend to make flashcards/store several selections of what I copied with the Rectangular Selection, I'd like to know what I can do to solve this issue.

Some useful information: I'm using macOS Sierra beta. I understand that this means I'll probably encounter more bugs than someone that isn't using the beta, but before installing a Release Candidate, I figured I could learn some stuff. I've tried deleting the .plists for Preview with no luck. When I zoom into the page (after pressing <kbd>⌘c</kbd> and the weirdness happening), the page probably re-renders and the problem goes away. If I press <kbd>⌘c</kbd> while zoomed in, the weirdness ensues.

Any advice on how to reinstall/format the app before that doesn't require a new installation would be much appreciated!

Comment: There's probably no reason to reinstall the OS. If you can reproduce this issue with the same document on a new user account, maybe file a bug report with Apple - openradar.appspot.com has some details on filing bugs.

Comment: Sierra is already on 10.12.1
Try that first.